# Can't get QuickAction to load

Tags: android

For a Android programming class i am trying to impliment a QuickAction Activity, but I can't get it to load in my program.  This is the code that I think is failing on load.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //show on iBtn1
        ImageButton iBtn1 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.iBtn1);
        iBtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        QuickActionBar.class));
            }

        });


        final QuickActionIcons edit = new QuickActionIcons();;

        edit.setTitle("Edit");
        edit.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edit));

        edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Edit Contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        final QuickActionIcons call = new QuickActionIcons();;

        call.setTitle("Call");
        call.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call));

        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Call Contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        final QuickActionIcons call3 = new QuickActionIcons();;

        call3.setTitle("Call3");
        call3.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call));

        call3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Toast.makeText(QuickActionSampleAppActivity.this,"Call Contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        final QuickActionIcons call1 = new QuickActionIcons();;

        call1.setTitle("Call 1");      
        call1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call));

        call1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Toast.makeText(QuickActionSampleAppActivity.this,"Call Contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        final QuickActionIcons call2 = new QuickActionIcons();;

        call2.setTitle("Call 2");       
        call2.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.call));

        call2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // Toast.makeText(QuickActionSampleAppActivity.this,"Call Contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        final QuickActionIcons send_data = new QuickActionIcons();;

        send_data.setTitle("Send Data");      
        send_data.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bluetooth));

        send_data.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //  Toast.makeText(QuickActionSampleAppActivity.this,"Start Transfer of Data",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        QuickActionBar qab = new QuickActionBar(iBtn1);
        qab.addItem(edit);
        qab.addItem(call);
        qab.addItem(send_data);
        qab.addItem(call1);
        qab.addItem(call2);
        qab.addItem(call3);
        qab.setAnimationStyle(QuickActionBar.GROW_FROM_LEFT);
        qab.show();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my LogCat

```
    01-30 17:16:39.650: E/Trace(810): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    01-30 17:16:39.650: W/Trace(810): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    01-30 17:16:39.650: W/Trace(810): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    01-30 17:16:39.650: W/Trace(810): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    01-30 17:16:40.038: W/Trace(810): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    01-30 17:16:40.038: W/Trace(810): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    01-30 17:16:41.618: D/dalvikvm(810): GC_CONCURRENT freed 67K, 7% free 2811K/3000K, paused 18ms+5ms, total 90ms
    01-30 17:16:41.618: D/dalvikvm(810): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 56ms
    01-30 17:16:41.638: I/dalvikvm-heap(810): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.933MB for 1127536-byte allocation
    01-30 17:16:41.718: D/dalvikvm(810): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 5% free 3909K/4104K, paused 74ms, total 75ms
    01-30 17:16:41.838: D/dalvikvm(810): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 4098K/4296K, paused 9ms+20ms, total 124ms
    01-30 17:16:42.058: D/AndroidRuntime(810): Shutting down VM
    01-30 17:16:42.058: W/dalvikvm(810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.rasmussen.mobile/edu.rasmussen.mobile.MainActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:567)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:993)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:847)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:811)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at edu.rasmussen.mobile.QuickActionBar.show(QuickActionBar.java:120)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at edu.rasmussen.mobile.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:141)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    01-30 17:16:42.108: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 11 more

Here are the Console
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] ------------------------------
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] Android Launch!
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] adb is running normally.
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] Performing edu.rasmussen.mobile.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Galaxy'
[2013-01-30 11:13:08 - GeoTag] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Galaxy'
[2013-01-30 11:13:13 - GeoTag] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-01-30 11:13:13 - GeoTag] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-01-30 11:14:50 - GeoTag] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-01-30 11:14:50 - GeoTag] Uploading GeoTag.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-01-30 11:14:50 - GeoTag] Installing GeoTag.apk...
[2013-01-30 11:16:28 - GeoTag] Success!
[2013-01-30 11:16:28 - GeoTag] Starting activity edu.rasmussen.mobile.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-01-30 11:16:31 - GeoTag] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=edu.rasmussen.mobile/.MainActivity }
```

Stacktrace

```
GeoTag [Android Application]    
    DalvikVM[localhost:8789]    
        Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
        Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
        Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

Comment: You better include why it is failing? (stacktrace,logcat etc.) instead of being angry on Google for no good reason. There are many opensource implemenations regarding QuickAction, no need to implement it in the framework. The framework supports PopUpWindow, this class has EVERYTHING to create a QuickAction (including handling touchevents, being a container on top of an activity, etc).

Comment: I'm not hateing on google in anyway shape or form, I was just suprised.

Comment: Can you include a stacktrace? if you want opensource implementations: download the app Android ui patterns, a few examples of quickaction there

Comment: Is there another Name for stacktrace in the Eclipse debug environment?

Comment: LogCat ;) Window > Show View > Other | open android tab > select LogCat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message:

> Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

You are trying to add a window on top of your activity when your activity isn't ready to process this (the window of the activity isn't shown yet). There are numerous ways of the dealing with this. One solution could be using a post-runnable, so the action will delayed.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // show your quick action here
   }
});
```

Comment: Cant figure where to put that code?  it doesn't like view.post

Comment: Well I changed view.post to iBtn1.post and I get a clean compile, so I am much closer.  When it runs I didn't expect my QuickActionBar to come up until I pressed the button.  More digging.  Thank you